# Component in iOS to make a selector option

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, components

I wonder which component is being used to create a selector option like the one used in iBooks where we can adjust the Font Size and also the Theme, but without moving to a new view controller.
In my application I would like to implement it giving 3 small options to the user to choose, but without moving the view controller being presented. Its a small square area with an arrow at the bottom or top side giving the impression where it's coming from. (Let me know if I am not clear with the explanation).
Does anybody know how to use it??
Thank you all in advance

Comment: a naive implementation would simply use a UIImageView that is 320 points wide (so it goes from edge to edge). The image would include the shadows, the "background" and the little arrow that points to the button. Then you add your UIControl as subviews of the imageView. If the position of the "source" button never changes you can get away with that easy approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ibooks is using UIView. In that UIView you can add any controls you like. You need to use delegate methods so that I can perform communication between two objects(send message to another object). You will be able to make you custom UIView as controls.